# No mono behaviour scripts in file. names DO match

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have recently installed unity, have a brand new project and any time I try to make any script I get the error

`"No Monobehaviour scripts in the file, or their names do not match the file name"`

[image]

Here is a picture of the script.

[image]

This DOES have the same name, and to my knowledge I am doing things right. Its the only script in project. Have tried in other empty projects, and looked everywhere else. Can not see why it is giving me this error. Can anyone tell me how to solve this?
EDIT: Here is the console error:
[image]

Comment: What is the error shown in the console?

Comment: No error, will show it in the question, editing now

Comment: What is the Unity Editor version?

Comment: @EmanuelVintilă 2019.2.9f1 , fresh install of visual studio code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I could not find the answer easily, incase someone stumbled upon this here is how it was solved.

> Go to "C:\Program
>   Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.2.14f1\Editor\Data\Tools\RoslynScripts"

and edit the "unity_csc.bat".

The line that looks like this

> %APPLICATION_CONTENTS%\Tools\Roslyn\csc

, add a .exe to, so it looks like

> %APPLICATION_CONTENTS%\Tools\Roslyn\csc.exe

Restart unity and I no longer have the error.

Comment: Thats a curious need, as obviously when running batch files, the .cmd, .exe, .bat, .com are all normal and expected command extensiuons

Comment: By default when you download unity the csc does not explicitly say .exe, normally windows 10 should be able to figure out the extension and run it, however it was unable to for some unknown reason. Figure with a problem this obscure its good to have it written incase someone else stumbles into this.

Comment: I think this problem occurs when the default launch method for executable files are modified in the registry. Consider cleaning you registry, you might face similar troubles with other apps in future.